# After upgrade to Windows 8.1, no Skydrive icon in task bar

Tags: sync, taskbar, icons, windows-8.1, onedrive

I upgraded to 8.1 and now I don't see the SkyDrive icon in the task bar, nor the green light under it indicating the my computer is communicating with SkyDrive. When I go into `Control Panel |..|Notification Area Icons`, SkyDrive is listed and noted as `Up to date`. However even though I mark it to `Show Icons and Notifications` I don't see any icon in the taskbar.

Is it supposed to be this way, or do I have a problem?

I kind of got used to that little green synchronizing indicator giving me a warm and fuzzy feeling.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/667549/how-to-see-if-skydrive-is-still-syncing-in-windows-8-1